# how to remove default namespaces and add custom namespace in root tag of xml using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

While creating xml from C# class I getting some default namespaces(`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) in root tag (Order) like below. but, I want to remove those default namespaces and I need the following namespace in the root tag (Order `xmlns="http://example.com/xml/1.0"`).
how to remove those default namespaces and replace in c# code. thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Number Type="mobile">9999999999</Number>
   <TrackStartDateTime>2015-05-30 11:00 ET</TrackStartDateTime>
   <Notifications>
      <Notification>
         <PartnerMPID>99999999</PartnerMPID>
         <IDNumber>L563645</IDNumber>
         <TrackDurationInHours>120</TrackDurationInHours>
         <TrackIntervalInMinutes>240</TrackIntervalInMinutes>
      </Notification>
   </Notifications>
   <Carrier>
      <Dispatcher>
         <DispatcherName>?</DispatcherName>
         <DispatcherPhone>0</DispatcherPhone>
         <DispatcherEmail>?</DispatcherEmail>
      </Dispatcher>
   </Carrier>
</Order>
```

I have used following C# classes.

```
    [XmlRoot("Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        [XmlElement("Number")]
        public Number Number;

        [XmlElement("TrackStartDateTime")]
        public string TrackStartDateTime;//TODO - need to check         

        [XmlElement("Notifications")]
        public Notifications Notifications;//TODO - notification tag should come inside Notifications tag

        [XmlElement("Carrier")]
        public Carrier Carrier;           

        public Order() {
            Number = new Number();
            Notifications = new Notifications();
            Carrier = new Carrier();
            TripSheet = new TripSheet();
        }
    }

    public class Number
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string Type;

        [XmlText]
        public Int64 Value;
    }

    public class Notifications {

        [XmlElement("Notification")]
        public List<Notification> Notification;
        public Notifications() {
            Notification = new List<Notification>();
        }

    }
    public class Notification
    {
        [XmlElement("PartnerMPID")]
        public string PartnerMPID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("IDNumber")]
        public string IDNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TrackDurationInHours")]
        public int TrackDurationInHours { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TrackIntervalInMinutes")]
        public int TrackIntervalInMinutes { get; set; }

    }
    public class Carrier
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name;

        [XmlElement("Dispatcher")]
        public Dispatcher Dispatcher;
        public Carrier() {
            Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        }

    }
    public class Dispatcher
    {
        [XmlElement("DispatcherName")]
        public string DispatcherName;

        [XmlElement("DispatcherPhone")]
        public Int64 DispatcherPhone;

        [XmlElement("DispatcherEmail")]
        public string DispatcherEmail;//conform format for email         

    }
```

and I have taken the new instance of Order Class and for testing purpose, I have hard-coded values for the each fields and I have used the following code for the creating xml from the C# class.

```
    public string CreateXML(Order order)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));  

        // Creates a stream whose backing store is memory. 
        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {                
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, order);//,ns  
            xmlStream.Position = 0;                
            //Loads the XML document from the specified string.
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure its a right approach for creating xml from C# classes. Please guide me to get the following xml output from c# class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order xmlns="http://example.com/xml/1.0" >
   <Number Type="mobile">9999999999</Number>
   <TrackStartDateTime>2015-05-30 11:00 ET</TrackStartDateTime>
   <Notifications>
      <Notification>
         <PartnerMPID>99999999</PartnerMPID>
         <IDNumber>L563645</IDNumber>
         <TrackDurationInHours>120</TrackDurationInHours>
         <TrackIntervalInMinutes>240</TrackIntervalInMinutes>
      </Notification>
   </Notifications>
   <Carrier>
      <Dispatcher>
         <DispatcherName>?</DispatcherName>
         <DispatcherPhone>0</DispatcherPhone>
         <DispatcherEmail>?</DispatcherEmail>
      </Dispatcher>
   </Carrier>
</Order>
```

Comment: what code do you use to generate this xml?

Comment: This sounds like it could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If I was to guess, you're using `XmlSerializer` to generate the XML.  The inclusion of default namespaces and the namespace for `Order` can be controlled during serialization.  If this is the case, include your serialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it... 
Just create a new `XDocument` and set the namespace that you want on it and transplant the original xml descendant into it, like so:

```
        var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Order xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Number Type=\"mobile\">9999999999</Number></Order>";

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);            

        var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://example.com/xml/1.0");
        var xdoc2 = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null),
                                 new XElement(ns + "Order", xdoc.Root.Descendants()));
```

See here for working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JYCL95

Answer (score 0):

For this case it should be sufficient to simply add a null namespace to the XMLRoot decoration used on your class definition.

```
[XmlRoot("Order", Namespace = null)]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public Number Number;

    [XmlElement("TrackStartDateTime")]
    public string TrackStartDateTime;         

    [XmlElement("Notifications")]
    public Notifications Notifications;

    [XmlElement("Carrier")]
    public Carrier Carrier;
```

The serializer should do the rest.